# Register a Cognito User Pool App Client with callback url to localhost with a sub domain and using http

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm using subdomains in my multitenant application and I'm trying to register a Cognito `app client` with a callback url to my locally running instance. However there is a limitation that the `http` protocol is only allowed for `localhost` callback urls. Unfortunately due to the subdomain Cognito doesn't recognise that the application is in fact running on `localhost` (`http://<subdomain>.localhost:8080/api/login/oauth2/code/cognito`) and doesn't allow me to use the callback url.

Does someone have experience with such situations and knows a workaround for that?

P.S. installing a self-signed certificate will probably solve the problem, but if there is another solution I would prefer it :)